# React Router with Suspense failing to render with React Router v5

Tags: react-router, react-suspense

We are trying to use this kind of construct, so that a component rendered through React Router can be Lazy loaded using React Suspense:

```
      <Route
        path="about"
        element={
          <React.Suspense fallback={<>...</>}>
            <About />
          </React.Suspense>
        }
      />
```

The official React Router with Suspense example on Stackblitz works fine with React Router v6:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-rkrnhn-jfpo9b?file=src%2FApp.tsx

However it does not work with React Router v5. Nothing gets rendered.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-rkrnhn?file=package.json

The only difference between the two above is the React Router version. We also see this behavior if we try to implement Suspense in our app.

React Router v6 still has some features missing like  [see this unsolved issue](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/8139) so I need a v5 solution.

Is some different syntax needed for v5?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React-router urls don't work when refreshing or writing manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually)

Comment: No, sorry. That looks to be something different, not related to React Suspense

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lazy loaded React router routes loading anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60250800/lazy-loaded-react-router-routes-loading-anyway)

Comment: @DrewReese that one seems to be more a case of the loading happening when not wanted. I'm just not seeing anything rendered at all in the failing example.

Comment: That was because they lazily loaded ***all*** their components, and then had some nested general components that triggered other dynamic imports to occur before they (*the OP*) was expecting them to. My answer there should get your code working though if you are trying to use per/route lazy loading working, it's using the v5 `Route` component API.

Comment: Thanks @Drew your method there got me working in our production code. Note though you have some typos in your withSuspense() (the <div> and props is not defined). I've accepted the answer below here, as Kanti has solved the Stackblitz example, although it didn't work fully in our real code.

Comment: Oh my.... that's a long time for a (*now very obvious*) typo to exist. I noticed a couple other discrepancies as well. Thanks for the heads up. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here i updated stackblitz for React Route v5 pls check.

```
<React.Suspense fallback={<>..</>}>
        <Switch>
          <Layout>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
            <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
          </Layout>
        </Switch>
      </React.Suspense>
```

you can find here with example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-rkrnhn-jt7p3e?file=src%2FApp.tsx)

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it works. Am travelling, will check in detail in ~1week.

Comment: Stackblitz update looks good - thanks. Had to use a different method to get our codebase working however, see comments by @Drew Reese

Comment: Souds good @Dan